# Windbg command .call usage and syntax

Tags: windows, windbg, program-analysis

I'm using Windbg to track all functions that could result in the blue screen errors. My method is to call certain suspects manually through windbg .call command. However, I always got syntax error. Here is my attempt.

```
nt!DbgBreakPointWithStatus:
fffff807`0d3c9cc0 cc              int     3
2: kd> .call WdFilter!SwitchToPanicMode(0,0)
                                           ^ Syntax error in '.call WdFilter!SwitchToPanicMode(0,0)'
2: kd> bp nt!EtwTracePageFault
2: kd> .call WdFilter!SwitchToPanicMode(this,0,0)
                                                ^ Syntax error in '.call WdFilter!SwitchToPanicMode(this,0,0)'
2: kd> .call /v nt!EtwTracePageFault(this,0x0)
                                             ^ Syntax error in '.call /v nt!EtwTracePageFault(this,0x0)'
2: kd> .call /v WdFilter!SwitchToPanicMode(this,0x0,0x0)
                                                       ^ Syntax error in '.call /v WdFilter!SwitchToPanicMode(this,0x0,0x0)'
2: kd> x /d /t nt!EtwTracePageFault
```

Suppose I have known that function SwitchToPanicMode takes in 2 function arguments, which .call format should I use to manually trigger the function? Or is there any way that can get around(maybe like use !analyze -v when the program crashes)?

Comment: Afaik .call is user mode live debugging only it doesnt work in kd or crash dumps

Comment: @blabb I think I have found the function. But changing the RIP directly to the function's address and use command g won't trigger the function. I looked up the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30282251/call-alternative-in-kernel-mode). It says I need a different address because ntdll!DbgBreakPoint is in user mode. Not sure how to get the address.